# MATLAB: error unzipping large files (above 4GB)

Tags: matlab, file, zip, unzip

I have a for loop that is iterating through around a hundred files, unzipping and performing some operation. It works great on 90 of these but on those files above around 4GB I get the error message: (Error using unzip (line 84) Invalid zip file "C:\filename.zip".)

Is there any way to unzip these larger files in MATLAB?

thanks

Comment: Sounds like windows thing. Isn't the limit of FAT32 4GB or something or am I completely mistaken?

Comment: Are you able to unzip the file at the command line?  Which OS are you running?

Comment: I'm using windows 7 professional, 3.60 GHz processor, 16.0 GB RAM, 64-bit operating system

Comment: and you file system is FAT32 isn't it...?

Comment: the file system is NTFS

Comment: I am able to open the zip at the command line with "rundll32.exe zipfldr.dll,RouteTheCall filename.zip"

Comment: For others: MATLAB's `unzip` uses java under the hood, and the exception for file sizes > 4 gigs comes from the `org.apache.tools.zip.ZipFile` call, which is inside a try/catch block.

Comment: This errors with R2016a as well.

Answer (score 1):

Using files above 4GB requires ZIP64, the MATLAB version you are using does not support it (Not sure if it was added in recent version).

For recent MATLAB versions which can use python libraries, use the python unzip commands (which support ZIP64). For older MATLAB versions look for an alternative library, for example Apache Commons Compress.

Comment: any suggestions for how to do this? My zip file is a huge image set..I try fh=py.open('file.zip'); z=py.zipfile.ZipFile(fh); and then imageset=z.extract('data/Intensity.data');--this loads for a while but I end up with a 1x49 empty set of strings rather than a 500x1500xhowever many images file

Comment: Unfortunately I can't further assist you, never used python to unzip and my MATLAB version is to old to old to have the python bridge. It was just the only library I knew which is already present. My recommendation: Try it with python first. If you already fail on that level, ask a new question. There are more experts on python than on python&matlab at the same time. If you fail to convert working python code to matlab, please show us the python code and I am sure someone here is able to properly call it from matlab.

Comment: Alright thanks, I think this has me going in the right direction anyways, much appreciated